# How to debug akka streams flows?

Tags: debugging, akka-stream

When I drop a breakpoint somewhere in method processLine, debugger does not stop at the line. It executes as if there is not any breakpoint .Is debugging akka streams flows somewhat different, how can i solve this issue?

```
val stream = source.
                 map( csvLine => A.processLine(csvLine)).
                 runWith(Sink)
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: What happens if you make the `map`-call multiline and put the BP on the A.processLine(csvLine)-line?

Comment: I use intellij . By the way , problem no longer exists, don't know for sure how .

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar issues with [ScalaIDE](http://scala-ide.org).

My solution has generally been to isolate my "business logic" from any akka dependencies:

```
//no akka imports required

case class Tweet(val author : String, val body : String)

def validAuthor(author : String) : Boolean = {
  author.trim().size > 0 && !author.equalsIgnoreCase("jk_rowling") //breakpoint works here
}
```

Then my asynchronous code becomes simple calls to the buz logic:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source, Sink}

val source : Source[Tweet,_] = ???

val flow = source.filter(validAuthor)
                 .runWith(Sink foreach println)
```

The IDE then obeys breakpoints in the buz logic, e.g. within `validAuthor`.

Comment: It  somehow resolved but i don't know why . I did not change any import statements .