# Akka: is there a Sink that never pulls?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

Need a `Sink` that never pulls, to use in unit tests.
Is there one already available or do I need to code it myself?

Please note that `Sink.ignore()` won't help, because it ALWAYS pulls.
I need a Sink that NEVER pulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Direct Answer**

You can create an [`org.reactivestreams.Subscriber`](https://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html) that never calls `Subscription.request`:

```
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber

def nonSubscriber[T] : Subscriber[T] = new Subscriber[T] {
  override def onComplete() : Unit = {}

  override def onError(throwable: java.lang.Throwable) : Unit = {}

  //should never be called therefore definition is not implemented
  override def onNext(t: T) : Unit = ???

  //does not call s.request
  override def onSubscribe(s: Subscription) : Unit = {}
}
```

This Subscriber can then be used to instantiate a `Sink`:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink

def nonSubscribingSink[T] : Sink[T, NotUsed] = 
  Sink.fromSubscriber[T](nonSubscriber[T])
```

**Indirect Answer**

The nature of the question suggest that you are mixing your "business logic" with your akka stream logic.  You may want to consider [a re-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742233/how-to-debug-akka-streams-flows/34000291#34000291) that could make the answer to your question unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up creating my own implementation:

```
// sink that does not pull
val snkStage = object : GraphStage<SinkShape<Message>>() {
    val shape = SinkShape(Inlet.create<Message>("in"))
    override fun shape() = shape
    override fun createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = object : GraphStageLogic(shape) {
        init {
            setHandler(shape.`in`()) {}
        }
    }
}
```

But then decided to use a more conventional combination of `Sink.ignore()` and `Source.maybe()` instead.